# Oracle SQL Spool Result file add spaces in columns

Tags: oracle, file, spool

I am spooling a big result in a file but the spool add a lot of space between columns :
one line is more than 6850 characters (mostly empty space), one column take 500 characters, for instance the first one :

```
 23053607                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ;
```

Here is the query :

```
    spool result.txt;

    set pagesize 0
    set linesize 8000
    SET TRIMSPOOL ON
    set heading off
    set space 0
    set trimout off
    set termout off
    set verify off
    set echo off
    set feed off
    set trimspool on
    -- set echo off;
    -- set termout off;
    set colsep ';'
    set feedback off;
    set pages 0;
    spool result.txt;

    select 
    trim(rec.Code) AS Code,
    trim(A.label) AS Number,
    trim(B.text) AS Syst
    FROM record rec
    join tableA A on A.rec_id = rec.rec_id
    join tableB B on B.kla_id = rec.kla_id;

    spool off;

    exit;
```

In the database there is no space.
How to avoid any spaces ?

Comment: You may use SQLcl (SQL Developer command line) to simplyfy creation of CSV by specifying `set sqlformat csv` or by using `/*+csv*/` hint. See the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/20.2/sqcug/working-sqlcl.html#GUID-E1EB4D88-D268-400E-BFA3-11F6F4755527)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing to do is to just concatenate the values. Remove colsep and try out:

```
SELECT rec.Code ||';'||
       A.label  ||';'||
       B.text   
  FROM record rec
       JOIN tableA A ON A.rec_id = rec.rec_id
       JOIN tableB B ON B.kla_id = rec.kla_id;
```

Comment: I get the error : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: It's because of the `AS` clauses. IT's considered a single column. Try the adjusted. When you're spooling you will need to make a select for the header row.

Comment: Thanks you , but can I use aliases without "AS" ? rec.Code Code ||';'|| A.label  number ||';'||

Comment: You can just do a dummy select from dual with the lines you want in your header: SELECT 'Code;Number;Syst' FROM dual`, you already have `SET HEAD OFF`. It solves the issue with the header, and there is no need to make aliases for the columns that way. It's all about what you have in the spool.